# The Pronunciation of 'i' at the Beginning of a Word

Tags: pronunciation

For years I took the pronunciation of "immersion" as the following.
https://howjsay.com/mp3/immersion.mp3
However, the "i" in the American pronunciation on [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=immersion%20pronunciation) is pronounced like "uh".

Which one is the correct pronunciation? I've also noticed this difference in many other words starting with "i" such as ["immense"](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=immense) and "[immediate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=immediate)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's merely a difference in accent. Both pronunciations are acceptable.

The former ("ih-mersion") would be received pronunciation (i.e. British English), the latter ("uh-mersion") would be commonly associated with certain American accents (it sounds Mid-west or Dixie).

That's not completely comprehensive, to be honest. Both pronunciations are heard everywhere in the English-speaking world. But "ih-mersion" is how you would pronounce the the word if you were trying to sound more formal and "uh-mersion" sounds informal and rural.

Comment: Please include details in the answer, not the comments. You can [edit] your answer at any time.